# Connection is busy with results for another hstmt in delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, odbc, driver, bde

i have developed a application in Delphi using Paradox and bde , now am migrating it into sql server 2008,

i have a lot of table and query components in every form, so am just create user DNS in ODBC manager with 'Sql Server - Driver' , and configure with BDE(connect sql server via BDE),

The problem is , while am working in some form, the error raised like

> Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

Am tried with Sql native clinet , but i gives lot of troubles for me, so am using sql-server driver,

please any one help me to fix this problem, or give a steps to migrate paradox to sql server wihtout using 3rd party componets and ado,,,,

Comment: The problem is probably with the BDE. It would be best to convert the application to use dbExpress or similar, which can handle multiple connections and is more server orientated.

Comment: A quick solution is to set the rowset size to -1 (`ROWSET SIZE`) with your TDatabase params (this will fetch all rows).

Comment: already i set rowset size to -1. even also the problem occur

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to set MARS_Connection=yes for your DSN.
2. `SQL Server Driver` has few issues when it works with SQL Server 2008. So, consider to use SQL Native Client 10.

Comment: Sql Server Driver does not have MARS_Connection option, am also tried with sql native client 10 but it gives Record is changed by another user problem,.